# What is the best way to learn Magento Theme development?

Tags: magento, magento-2.3

I have a new task that I am currently undergoing and it involves learning to develop magento themes that can be installed on an existing store or on a new store.

I am currently having a hard time getting to know how magento renders templates and want to know if there is a good way of learning magento theme development

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked on the official magento 2 website there is a pretty aloborate documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

If you want to create a new theme I think you can best start from blank and not Luma.  If you have to do little changes luma is good start.